# Data synchronization (validation) between two clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have a webshop built on ASP.NET Boilerplate (Angular frontend and MSSQL database).
The webshop contains items and I want to keep an inventory of these items. 
Every time an order is created the inventory is updated. So basically I have a database with Webshops, Items and Orders.
I have repositories and managers for these objects.

All works fine, but the issue occurs when two clients at the same time load the webshop.

Client1 opens webpage:

- Webshop1

  - Item1: "10 items available"
  - Item2: "8 items available"

Client2 opens webpage at the same time:

- Webshop1

  - Item1: "10 items available"
  - Item2: "8 items available"

The first one that buys all the available items, should be able to create an order and the second one should get an error.

When an order is created, the backend checks if there are enough items available.
But when the webshop is loaded BEFORE the order of the first client is created, the second client does not know the updated inventory and will be able to create the order as well.
Meaning 20 items of Item1 can be sold!

How do I "sync" the data between the two sessions in the backend? It seems somehow the data is cached in the backend when loading the webshop.

CreateOrder function

```
public async Task<CreateOrderResponseDto> Create(CreateOrderDto input, long? userId)
{
    input.OrderItems.ForEach(async o =>
    {
        if (!(await _salesItemManager.ReserveStock(o.SalesItemId, o.Quantity)).IsSuccess)
        {
            throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("OrderItem", "OrderItemCreate");
        }
    });


    var salesPage = await _salesPageManager.Get(input.SalesPageId, false);

    if (salesPage.GetState() != StatePage.Published)
    {
        throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("Order", "PageNotAvailable");
    }

    if (salesPage.CommentsRequired.HasValue && salesPage.CommentsRequired.Value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.Description))
        {
            throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("Order", "CommentsRequired");
        }
    }

    var order = new Order
    {
        Address = input.Address,
        City = input.City,
        LastName = input.LastName,
        Name = input.Name,
        PostalCode = input.PostalCode,
        Email = input.Email,
        PhoneNumber = input.PhoneNumber,
        Description = input.Description,
        SalesPage = salesPage
    };


    try
    {
        order.Price = await _salesItemManager.GetPriceByOrders(input.OrderItems);
        order = await _orderRepository.InsertAsync(order);

        input.OrderItems.ForEach(async o =>
        {
            var orderItem = new OrderItem();
            orderItem.SalesItemId = o.SalesItemId;
            orderItem.OrderId = order.Id;
            orderItem.Quantity = o.Quantity;

            await _orderItemRepository.InsertAsync(orderItem);
        });

        if (input.SelectedSalesPageOptionId.HasValue)
        {
            order.SalesOption = await _salesPageManager.GetOption(input.SelectedSalesPageOptionId.Value);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("OrderItem", "OrderItemCreate");
    }

    if (userId.HasValue && salesPage.User.Id == userId.Value)
    {
        var payment = await _paymentManager.CreateManualPayment(order, input.IsPaid);
        order.Payment = payment;

        return new CreateOrderResponseDto() { IsSuccess = true, PaymentUrl = string.Empty, OrderId = order.Id.ToString() };
    }
    else
    {
        var payment = await _paymentManager.CreatePayment(order);
        order.Payment = payment;
        return new CreateOrderResponseDto() { IsSuccess = true, PaymentUrl = payment.PaymentUrl, OrderId = order.Id.ToString() };
    }
}
```

ReserveStock function

```
public async Task<GeneralDto> ReserveStock(Guid itemId, int quantity)
{
    var salesItem = await _salesItemRepository.GetAsync(itemId);

    if (salesItem == null || salesItem.Stock == null || salesItem.ReservedStock == null)
        return new GeneralDto() { IsSuccess = false };

    if (salesItem.Stock < quantity)
    {
        return new GeneralDto() { IsSuccess = false };
    }

    salesItem.Stock -= quantity;
    salesItem.ReservedStock += quantity;

    try
    {
        await _salesItemRepository.UpdateAsync(salesItem);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("SalesItem", "SalesItemUpdate");
    }

    return new GeneralDto() { IsSuccess = true };
}
```

Comment: I added some code. As you can see I just want to create an error when creating the order if the ReserveStock function fails. But the salesItem repository isn't yet updated from the latest order if the webshop was opened at two locations at the same time and one of the clients creates an order. When I open the webshop after an order is create there is no problem, than the salesitem is updated.

Comment: This is a standard concurrency issue (aka "race condition").  You are going to implement a lock system in order to keep the second request from processing while the first request is in process. In general, concurrency issues and locks can be a pretty big subject.  I'd recommend doing some research on how to deal with this using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the data is cached.

The problem is that your `ReserveStock` checks are async tasks that are not awaited by the caller:

```cs
input.OrderItems.ForEach(async o =>
{
    if (!(await _salesItemManager.ReserveStock(o.SalesItemId, o.Quantity)).IsSuccess)
    {
        throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("OrderItem", "OrderItemCreate");
    }
});
```

Assign your async `ReserveStock` checks to an array of tasks that is awaited by the caller:

```cs
var reserveStockChecks = input.OrderItems.Select(async o =>
{
    if (!(await _salesItemManager.ReserveStock(o.SalesItemId, o.Quantity)).IsSuccess)
    {
        throw CodeException.ToAbpValidationException("OrderItem", "OrderItemCreate");
    }
}).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(reserveStockChecks);
```